# return success data in require.js with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

i have a little understanding problem with my current code...

i create a new require js module.

```
define(['jquery','apiomat'],function($,Apiomat) {

var getLocation = function(data, callback) {
    Apiomat.Localization.getLocalizations("locale like 'de'", {

        data: data,

        onOk: function (data) {
            callback(data);
        }
    });
};

return {
    getData: function(data, callback) {
        getLocation(data, callback);
    }
}
```

});

And if i try to access these function with:

```
var test = easy.getData();
app.logger("CALLBACK FROM COMMON: " + JSON.stringify(test));
```

I always get this error message.

**TypeError: callback is not a function. (In 'callback(data)', 'callback' is undefined)**

Im not really sure what i have done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getData` takes two arguments. The second one is supposed to be a function, but you aren't passing any arguments at all, so it gets the value `undefined`.

It then calls `getLocation` with the same arguments and `Apiomat.Localization.getLocalizations` does its thing. Eventually `getLocalizations` (or another function called by it) calls `getOK` which attempts to call `callback`.

`undefined` is not a function, so you get the error message.

---

Additionally the `getData` function doesn't have a `return` statement so will be returning `undefined`. This means there is no point in assigning the return value to `test`.

---

You need to pass a function which does whatever you want to do:

```
function myCallback(test) {
    app.logger("CALLBACK FROM COMMON: " + JSON.stringify(test));
}
```

… and pass arguments to `getData`.

```
easy.getData("some data", myCallback);
```

Comment: yeah it work´s. thanks a lot man :-) now i have understand the callback function well.